# Cannot access a file using java.io.FileInputStream

Tags: 14.04, java, drive, paths

I am working with java servlets and I need to access a file trail.xlsx within the java code using java.io.Fileinputstream class, for windows we have to add the drive letter but here we don't have any drive letter to get the full qualified path for file like

```
c:\something\trial.xlsx
```

and even I have tried following combinations

```
/home/trail.xlsx

/media/win7/trail.xlsx
```

(moving the file to the following locations first)
Why aren't these addresses working with java is it that java does not support linux drive paths?? or there is other way out??I need to read that file only within java and it says

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/trail.xlsx
```

Thank you for you valuable time....

Comment: Did you run java servlet into tomcat container?

Comment: yes i am using eclipse it does everything for me

Comment: I'm not sure, but may be going to depend from what ecplipse/tomcat prepend to /home/trail.xslt

Comment: Is it possible that java does not know anything about Ubuntu File system herarchy

Comment: I use tomcat on linux redhat and it works fine. I thought at a workspace of ecplipse.

Comment: @Letizia - I cannot understand your last line I thought at a workspace of ecplipse??

Comment: sorry I was wrong to write eclipse. try getAbsolutePath() on File("/") object. If you are running Tomcat into eclipse, you should have a workspace of your project, and Tomcat is defined as server with its hostname. Tomcat configuration should define a virtual host associated to hostname and associated to application. This was what I meant by the word "workspace".

Comment: can you elaborate?? I mean exact method??

Comment: In your jsp file try `File d = new File("/"); String output = "<p>"+d.getAbsolutePath()+"</p>"` and print into your page the result. This method will show the real path used to access file "/".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me rephrase my earlier 'answer' - I don't think I adequately communicated my intent.

In my twelve years of Java programming, I've used the java.io.File abstraction dozens of times in web apps and in stand-alone apps, on Linux file systems and on Windows file systems, (and Java works with Linux file systems just fine).

In my estimation, the cause of more than 90% of FileNotFoundExceptions is minor typing errors in the file system path or file name embedded in the Java program that cause the program to attempt to access a non-existent file rather than the file that the programmer intended it to access.

**GIVEN** that your original post cited file extensions for an Excel spreadsheet as 'xslx' and that your current post still cites **trial.xslx** and **trail.xslx** file names, (yes, they are just simple typing errors, but simple typing errors are my best guess at the cause of your problem given the information you've provided above)

**THEN** my answer is that you need to ensure that the path name and file name. (especially the file name extension), that is used in your Java program match the path and file name of the file you are looking to access **exactly**.  And remember, Linux file paths are **case-sensitive**, unlike the Windows file system.

**FINALLY**, if you have confirmed that your file path is not the problem, post the Java code that is being executed when the exception is thrown, and I will be happy to check further into it.

**OR**, refer to the following:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

for all the gritty details of working with Java IO components.